# Calculating numbers with operators

Tags: c, operators

Can anyone explain to me how this code is being calculated using operators.

```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main(void)
  {

   int x = 2, y , z;

   x *= 3;
   printf("%d\n", x);
   x = x * (3 + 2);
   printf("%d\n", x);
   x *= y = z = 4;
   printf("%d\n", x);
   x *= y += z;
   printf("%d %d %d\n", x, y, z);

   return 0;
  }
```

As a result, I got the following output:

> 6,
>   30,
>   120,
>   960, 8, 4,

Comment: Did you try to step through using a debugger? Which part you don;t understand?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: How can you get as a second result 120. Isnt x * (3+2) = 10?

Comment: The code is  x = x * (3 + 2);

Comment: No, x == 6 at that point. You multiplied 2 * 3. Then 6 * (3 + 2) == 30.

Comment: Aha i didnt know it remembered the value from the previous statement.

Comment: It is not a matter of "remembering" it is a matter of the definition of assignment. You explicitly set it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator followed by an equal sign means that the operator is applied to the variable on the left and the variable on the right, followed by an assignment to the variable on the left. You also follow the precedence operations. I have expanded the meaning below.

```
x *= 3;
```

is the same as

```
x = x * 3;  // 6 = 2*3
```

The parentheses shows order of precedence

```
x = x * (3+2) // x was 6 from the previous line
```

this is

```
x = x * 5 // which gives 30
```

next

```
x *= y = z = 4;
```

means

```
z = 4;
y = z; //which is 4
x = x *y; // which is 120 = 30 *4
```

next

```
x *= y += z;
```

means

```
y = y + z ; // y = 4 + 4 (8)
x = x * y; // x = 120 * 8 (960)
```

Answer (score 2):

`*=` multiplies left operand by right operand and assigns result to left.

```
x *= y = z = 4;
```

Works right to left, assigning 4 to z and y then multiplying x by 4.

```
x *= y += z;
```

z is added to y and result is assigned to y, then x is multiplied by y and result is assigned to x.

Comment: How can you get as a second result 120. Isnt x * (3+2) = 10?

Comment: x was modified in the previous statement
x *= 3; this means x=x*3; and x initial value was 2, so after this it becomes 6. 
6 * (3 +2) = 30
30 * 4 = 120

Comment: Aha this is what bothered me. So the fist x means the new walue, the second x is has already a value from past.

Comment: @ŽigaGazvoda: Why do you think `x` would snap back to being 2 after you changed it to 6?

Answer (score 2):

`x*=3` means `x=x*3` => `x=2*3=6`

`x*=(3+2)` means `x=x*(3+2)` => `x=6*5=30`

`x*=y=z=4` means `z=4`, then `y=4`, then `x=x*y` => `x=30*4=120`

`x*=y+=z` means `y=y+z` then `x=x*y` => `y=4+4=8` then `x=120*8=960`.

Answer (score 1):

- The first two assignments are straightforward: multiplying `x` by `3` gives you `6`, and then by `(3+2)` gives you `30`.
- The third assignment features a chain of assignments, with `4` assigned to `y` and `z`. Since the value of an assignment is always the value of its left side after the assignment, the final multiplication `x *= y` multiplies `x` by `4`, giving you `120`.
- The last line is the trickiest, because it features two side effects. First, `y += z` is evaluated, producing `8`. After that `x` is multiplied by `8`, producing its final value of `960`.

Note that in the last line `x` is multiplied by `8`, which may or may not be the value of `y` at the time the multiplication is performed.